# Removing fid from the GeoServer layer

Tags: postgis, geoserver, postgresql, sql, web-gis

In my PostGIS table, I do not have any column with feature ID or FID.

[image: PostGIS Table Columns]

But when I open it in GeoServer layer, It shows the FID

[image: Highlighted column : fid]

but I don't want to show it when i click over the polygon,

Is there any way to do that?

And even if I am writing the PostGres table with fid, it is not using this as fid

[image: fid]

however I am using this column as Identifier in the Geoserver SQL view, but still getting the postgres generated fid.

[image: id]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to remove it from the HTML feature info, you can modify the Freemarker template generating the output, which looks as follows:
https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/blob/master/src/wms/src/main/resources/org/geoserver/wms/featureinfo/content.ftl

This guide shows how to setup your custom feature info templates:
https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/GetFeatureInfo/html.html

However, it cannot be removed from the other GetFeatureInfo output formats, the "fid" is the feature id, a mandatory element in many of them (in your case, it seems you don't have a primary key in your table that could serve as identity, so GeoServer is making one up at each request... that's generally bad practice, GeoServer will work better if you actually add a primary key).

Comment: Hi Andrea, now while writing the table to postgis, i am already passing the fid as, df.to_postgis(con=engine, name='table', if_exists = 'replace', index=True, index_label = "fid"), and while editing the SQL view of GeoServer layer, as SELECT fid, issue_date, forecast_date, state_name, district_name, rainfall, geometry FROM table WHERE "issue_date" = (SELECT MAX("issue_date") FROM table). I am also checking the fid column as Identifier in SQL query of GeoServer layer, but it showing this fid as just another column and showing the self generated ID in the table same as figure above.

Comment: In the Geopandas GeoDataframe I have already added another column as fid, so that it can use this column as identifier, and the tables in postgres are being written properly. But how should I replace this added fid column with the postgres generated fid?